# How can I get Python to use upper case letters when printing hexadecimal values?

Tags: python, formatting, hex, uppercase

In Python v2.6 I can get hexadecimal for my integers in one of two ways:

```
print(("0x%x")%value)
print(hex(value))
```

However, in both cases, the hexadecimal digits are lower case. How can I get these in upper case?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Capital X (Python 2 and 3 using [sprintf-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)):

```
print("0x%X" % value)
```

Or in python 3+ (using [`.format` string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)):

```
print("0x{:X}".format(value))
```

Or in python 3.6+ (using [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)):

```
print(f"0x{value:X}")
```

Comment: See my answer for the more Python 3 idiom using f-strings: `print(f'0x{value:X}')`

Comment: Yes. I'm saying `%` is the older operator hangover from 2.x which while not officially deprecated, is discouraged. [Python 3.6+ finally allows variable interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-20) like we've wanted ever since 3.0 and `.format()`.

Comment: It's not much of a "Python 3 idiom" if it fails on 6/8 of all released versions of python 3 (although admittedly most are EOL)

Comment: yes it is, and you're missing the point. This answer is an old near-deprecated 2.x idiom that is only still kept alive in 3.x because they messed up the transition to `format()` back in 3.0. As of today, "3.x" means "3.6+" or "3.7", where f-strings are awesome. [3.6 was a huge advance for string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-20). People today should be learning f-strings. `%`-formatting-operator was planned to be deprecated but they got pushback because it's in a lot of legacy code.

Comment: _'As of today, "3.x" means "3.6+" or "3.7"'_ - in my experience, this is not true. For me, 3.x means "the earliest version of python 3 that my package will support", which typically is "all non-EOL python 3.x". _"where f-strings are awesome"_ - you're not wrong about that.

Comment: All of these give the wrong result if your value is negative. You get `0x-FF` when what you want is `-0xFF`.

Answer (score 9):

`print(hex(value).upper().replace('X', 'x'))`

Handles negative numbers correctly.

Comment: Although it seems a little more clunky, this answer is the one that addresses negative numbers and also does not leave X uppercase, but adheres to the standard of x being lowercase.  +1

Answer (score 5):

By using uppercase `%X`:

```
>>> print("%X" % 255)
FF
```

Updating for Python 3.6 era: Just use 'X' in the format part, inside f-strings:

```
print(f"{255:X}")
```

(f-strings accept any valid Python expression before the `:` - including  direct numeric expressions and variable names).

Answer (score 5):

Just use upper().

```
intNum = 1234
hexNum = hex(intNum).upper()
print('Upper hexadecimal number = ', hexNum)
```

Output:

```
Upper hexadecimal number =  0X4D2
```

Comment: But I don't think "0X4D2" is the correct notation. It should be "0x4D2" (lowercase "x").

Comment: '%X' is best. @PeterMortensen is correct. This way, you'd need something clunky like `''.join([ '0x', hex(value).upper()[2:] ])`

Answer (score 3):

The more Python 3 idiom using f-strings would be:

```
value = 1234
print(f'0x{value:X}')
'0x4D2'
```

Notes (and why this is not a duplicate):

- shows how to **avoid capitalizing the '0x' prefix**, which was an issue in other answers
- shows **how to get variable interpolation** `f'{value}'`; nobody actually ever puts (hardcoded) hex literals in real code. There are plenty of pitfalls in doing variable interpolation: it's not `f'{x:value}'` nor `f'{0x:value}'` nor `f'{value:0x}'` nor even `f'{value:%x}'` as I also tried. So many ways to trip up. It still took me 15 minutes of trial-and-error after rereading four tutorials and whatsnew docs to get the syntax. This answer shows how to get f-string variable interpolation right; others don't.

Comment: @wim: No it's not a) jsbueno's answer show neither how to avoid capitalizing the '0x' prefix, nor b) how to get variable interpolation `f'{value}'`; nobody actually puts hex literals in real code. And there are pitfalls in doing interpolation: it's not `f'{x:value}'` nor `f'{0x:value}'` nor `f'{value:0x}'`. Many ways to trip up. I show how not to.